# Three.js Progress Loader not hiding when model loaded

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a page based on [this](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs424/notes2013/threejs/json-loader-demo.html) example, and using the relevant lines from the webgl_material_bumpmap example for implementing a loading progress Dom Element.

The page is (temporarily) [here](http://khuts.org/models/samples.html). If what I have included below is not enough information, please see the source for this page.

My problem is that the Loading text block does not disappear when the model is loaded. 
I show it using:

```
function installModel(file) { 
    if (model) {**strong text**
        scene.remove(model);
        }
        render();
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);
    loader.load("obj/" + file, modelLoadedCallback);
        document.body.appendChild( loader.statusDomElement );
        }
```

The init function (without the error handling stuff) is

```
   scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, theCanvas.width/theCanvas.height, 0.1, 100);
    camera.position.z = 30;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.damping = 0.3;
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    createWorld();
    installModel("room1.json");
    render();

loader.statusDomElement.style.display = "none";

 }
```

Why does the Loading text remain visible?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add:

```
loader.statusDomElement.style.display = "none";
```

in your callback function `modelLoadedCallback()` after you print to the console.

Comment: If I add the display style to the call back function, I get an error saying "Cannot read property 'statusDomElement' of undefined"

Comment: is the variable `loader` defined where you call it?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out.
I had to add another div element called "prog"
then

```
var show
     function show() {
       document.getElementById("prog").style.display = "inline";
        }
```

and

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(true);
    document.getElementById("prog").appendChild(loader.statusDomElement );
    loader.load("obj/" + file, modelLoadedCallback);
```